# GitHub Actions - Add Submodule

Tags: github-actions, git-submodules

## Problem

I want to be able to add a submodule automatically using GitHub Actions.

I have tried using the following command (since it works fine when run locally on my computer)

```
name: Trigger to Add New Submodule

on:

  repository_dispatch:
    types: [ trigger-add-new-submodule ]

jobs:
  addSubmodule:
    name: Add Submodule
    runs-on: [ self-hosted, windows ]

    steps:    
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.MY_TOKEN || secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          submodules: recursive
          
      - name: Pull  
        run: git pull
        
      - name: Add Submodule
        run: git submodule add URL PATH
```

However, when it is running through the GitHub Actions it appears to have frozen.

<strike>I am not sure if it is waiting for user input, or stuck for some other reason.</strike>

I used GitHub Hosted instead of self-hosted and got the following output.

```
fatal: Cannot prompt because user interactivity has been disabled.
bash: line 1: /dev/tty: No such device or address
error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such file or directory
```

It appears to be an issue with lack of user interactivity.
I am not sure how to allow this, since I cannot use `with: token:` with `run:`

## Question

Is this even the right way to go about doing this?

I couldn't find any pre-built GitHub Actions to do this, so I figured I should just use the git commands directly.

Is this the correct command to be using, or is there another command that would work better?

Comment: Curious as why you want to do this in GHA?  Either way if you can share more of the job yaml that would help debug if it is a syntax issue.

Comment: @aknosis I want to be able to automatically add repositories as submodules to my main repository, since the main repo is a collection of libraries that creates an installer. If a new repo is added, a new installer including that new library needs to be created. 

These repositories are being created from a template, so they will have the required actions to trigger this when first pushed. But currently, I have to manually add the new repo as a submodule, which is not ideal.

I have added the full yaml for reference.

Comment: Seems relatively straight forward and your syntax looks correct. You will need to git add and push your changes see: https://github.com/actions/checkout#push-a-commit-using-the-built-in-token. Not sure why it would freeze though, possibly token can't be used with the url provided?

Comment: @aknosis I've added a fault that I was able to get to come up after changing from self-hosted to GitHub hosted.

Comment: @aknosis It appears to have an issue because of lack of user interactivity. However, when I run this command on my computer, not user interactivity is required. I am not sure how to get past this step. It appears to want credentials, but I cannot use `with: token:` with `run:`

Comment: Are you using https or ssh url to .git?

Comment: @aknosis I am using https. Would ssh be better?

Comment: I believe using ssh is what would allow reuse of the token from actions/checkout.